# Does Eclipse or Netbeans offer better support for JavaFX development?

Tags: software-development, java, ide

Which IDE does offer better support to start a JavaFX project from scratch?

More specific: Are the following tasks better supported in Eclipse or Netbeans:

- Assistance for project creation
- Autocompletion
- Code generation
- Drag & drop GUI creation (Scene Builder)?

Or is there a third IDE, that's even better equiped to support these use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse will be better than NetBeans, but NetBeans is not bad though.

- Both of the IDEs provide good assistance.
- Both of them have auto completion feature. In Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does it. NetBeans also has a key combination to do it, I forgot it.
- Both support code generation (unimplemented methods are implemented automatically).
- Scene Builder is a little better in Eclipse than NetBeans, in my opinion.

Both the IDEs are good and provide user support very well. We can find many tutorials using these 2 than any other IDE. Both have many things in common and operating them is almost same. Finally, I support Eclipse a bit more than NetBeans.

Answer (score 4):

There is a special build of Eclipse known as e(fx)clipse which provides lots of tooling for JavaFX.

More at [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)